# Error Resolving Thymeleaf Templates Files when run a jar file in Spring Boot App but runs fine locally

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-security, thymeleaf

My app works fine on local. But when I deploy to kubernetes I get this error:

Error resolving template [login], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String referrer = request.getHeader("Referer");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        request.getSession().setAttribute("Referer", referrer);
        modelAndView.setViewName("user/test");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Test</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/reminder").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/reset").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/update-password").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "MODERATOR", "USER")

                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().successHandler(customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                //                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .and()
                .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers(new String[]{"/api/**"}).and();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param web
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.expressionHandler(new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler() {
            @Override
            protected SecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi) {
                WebSecurityExpressionRoot root = (WebSecurityExpressionRoot) super.createSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication, fi);
                root.setDefaultRolePrefix(""); //remove the prefix 
                return root;
            }
        }).ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/resources/**",
                "/static/**",
                "/assets/**",
                "/global_assets/**",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/js/**",
                "/img/**"
        ).antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/css/**", "/js/**");
    }
```

application.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=html
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.servlet.content-type=text/html
```

How can I solve this problem? I am using spring boot and kubernetes. It does not bring up the login page.